# Adding Firebase Admin SDK to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to add a Firebase Admin SDK to my Swift based application. But the options that are there only have Node, Java, and Python.

Would I have to convert to Swift from one of these other languages? Correct me if I am going in the wrong direction, I am still pretty inexperienced. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Firebase Admin SDK in the client is not supported, nor would you want it to be. Since Admin gives unrestricted access to the entire database, you would be putting your data at risk. A user could potentially find a way to read and write anything in the database, and even delete all of your data. That being said, what were you planning on doing with the Admin SDK? Perhaps I can steer you toward a different strategy.

Comment: I wanted to use the Admin access to allow another app (from my side) to control the content for all other users on the database. It is like a two part application with admin control and user access

Comment: Use database security rules to control who has access to which parts of your database. You could make a rule that a specific uid has access to certain data if you anticipate only one person having said access. Check out the documentation to find out more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

For a group of users to have access, it's a bit more complex. This post does a great job of walking through what to do: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/group-security-in-firebase-database.html

Comment: What about swift on the server though? There is a gap here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of Firebase Admin for Swift. Please check out this GitHub repository I created, https://github.com/1amageek/FirebaseAdmin. It's a Swift implementation of the Firebase Admin SDK and might be what you're looking for. Give it a try and see if it meets the requirements of your project!